# Hibernate 5.0.11 does not log bind values

Tags: spring, hibernate, wildfly

I have pretty much tried every solutions available on this site and others but I cannot get to log hibernate bind values.

Environment:

```
Spring 4
Hibernate 5.0.11
Wildfly 10.1.0
```

logging configuration in standalone.xml

```
        <logger category="org.hibernate">
            <level name="INFO"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.hibernate.type">
            <level name="TRACE"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="net.sf.hibernate.type">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.hibernate.SQL">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.hibernate.hql">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
```

Hibernate properties look like this:

```
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show-sql","true");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql","true");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments","true");
```

I can see queries and comments just fine but no bind parameters and values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be the `org.hibernate.type` category. I used the following CLI commands and ran the [kitchensink quick start](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/11.x/kitchensink) which seemed to work.

```
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=level, value=TRACE)
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.hibernate.type:add(level=TRACE)
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.hibernate.SQL:add(level=DEBUG)
```

This is the output I got.

```
20:10:52,000 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] (default task-9) call next value for hibernate_sequence
20:10:52,034 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] (default task-9) insert into Member (email, name, phone_number, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
20:10:52,036 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] (default task-9) binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [test@example.com]
20:10:52,037 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] (default task-9) binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [Test User]
20:10:52,037 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] (default task-9) binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [5555555555]
20:10:52,037 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] (default task-9) binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - [1]
```

The `binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [test@example.com]` messages the ones you're looking for.

Comment: I have to confess its my fault. I was using eclipse to run this and wildfly was running inside eclipse. So no bind values were displayed in wildfly console inside eclipse. After i saw your post, i saw the log file and it had the trace information about the values. Now i need make sure that output goes to console as well. Thanks for trying this out.

Comment: This ensured log went to console as well         <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="TRACE"/>
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="CONSOLE-PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>